# Logging in a React app with Selenium using ReduxPersist

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, react-redux, redux-persist

For an investigation I'm doing, I'm trying to programmatically log in to a React web app, and I can't use the log in form each time, I need to pretend that I'm just coming back to the site.

The app does not use session cookies to identify logged in users, but a mix of values in IndexedDB and LocalStorage.

My code looks like this (happy to provide you with the name of the website in a private message) but fails to successfully log in. When the website is visited for the second time, the selenium browser is not logged in. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
cookies = {
   # All cookies set by the domain.
}

local_storage = {
   # All key value pairs found in the local storage
   # of a browser connected to the website.
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(website_url)
time.sleep(5)
for key, value in local_storage.items():
    driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem('%s', '%s');" % (key, value))

for key, value in cookies.items():
    driver.add_cookie({"name": key,
                       "value": value,
                       "domain":domain_url,
                       "path": "/"})

driver.execute_script(""" 
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("keyval-store", 1);

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
db = request.result;
console.log("success: "+ db);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("keyval");
    objectStore.add(value_found_in_the_IndexedDB,"reduxPersist:user");
    objectStore.add(another_value_found_in_the_IndexedDB, "reduxPersist:appSettings");
};
    """)
time.sleep(5)

driver.get(website_url)

time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: We can't help you without your code.

Comment: @JohannesFilter Because all that was missing were the credentials, I sent you the whole code in an e-mail.

Comment: The most important information was the website. 